# snowflake - get Quarter of a date format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run this query to convert the timestamp column to its quarter equivalent:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, 'QUARTER') AS "X LABEL", Count(*) AS "X VALUE" FROM TABLE
 GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,'QUARTER') ORDER BY  "X LABEL"
```

But my result set is not returning the proper quarter group (1-4) and instead is returning the count of the whole table.

Note that I need to use TO_CHAR as I cannot explicitly modify the query for the sake of Quarter format.

Sample output that I want to achieve:

```
X Label | XValue
--------+--------
1       + 10
2       + 15
3       + 20
4       + 25
```

Comment: can you provide a example of the output you want please

Comment: edited to provide @SimeonPilgrim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [QUARTER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/year.html)

```
SELECT
    QUARTER(LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) AS "X LABEL", 
    Count(*) AS "X VALUE" 
FROM VALUES 
    ('2022-01-01'::date),
    ('2022-01-01'::date),
    ('2022-05-01'::date),
    ('2022-07-01'::date),
    ('2022-12-01'::date)
    t(last_modified_date)
GROUP BY  "X LABEL"
```

gives:

| X LABEL | X VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

`DATE_TRUNC('QUARTER', date)` can be useful also, or using `YEAR(date), QUARTER(date)`

Comment: As I said in my question: Note that I need to use TO_CHAR as I cannot explicitly modify the query for the sake of Quarter format.

Comment: The selection of FORMAT specifiers that work are at https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html#date-and-time-formats-in-conversion-functions